# TableView cell frame problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing an application that has a view as shown in image.
I am having a table view.
My problem is how will I show my chat boxes cell some right to the original Table viewcell frame. [image]

Like The white box is some right to the original table view cell

code:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    int row = [indexPath section];

    UITableViewCell *startCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 200, 50)  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    UITableViewCell *durationCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 200, 100) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    UITableViewCell *radiusCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 200, 150) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    startCell.textLabel.text = @"Start:";
    durationCell.textLabel.text = @"Duration:";
    radiusCell.textLabel.text = @"radius";


    if (row == 0)
    {
        return startCell;
    }
    else if (row == 1)
    {
        return durationCell;
    }

    return radiusCell;


}
```

Comment: does your cell contains imageView ?

Comment: @maulik no it does not contain any thing.

Comment: try to use of switch case like switch (indexPath.row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your cell contains UIImageView then you have to create custom cells . In custom cell 's .m file you have to create a method called `- (void)layoutSubviews` in that method write code for image view like

```
   `CGRectMake frame= CGRectMake(5, 12, 19, 15);    
    myImageView.frame = frame;`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set frame of the view which is inside cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method or you can make custom cell and position it where ever you want.